# React SetState ReRenders Array of Elements Slow

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm wondering what the best way to do this..

Parent Component:

```
export class Parent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      ranks: {},
    }
  }

  handleClick = (item) => {
    const newState = update(this.state, { ranks: { [item]: { $set: item } } });
    this.setState(newState);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ChildList ranks={ this.state.ranks } onClick={ (item) => handleClick(item) />
    )
  }
}
```

Child List Component:

```
const list = ['example', 'of', 'long', 'list', 'of', 'strings'];

export const ChildList = (props) => (
  list.map(item => <Child key={ item } item={ item } onClick={ props.onClick } />);
);
```

Child Component:

```
export const Child = (props) => (
  <div onClick={ () => props.onClick(props.item) }>
    { props.item }
  </div>
);
```

What I'm trying to do:

When I click on one of the many Child components, I want to set state on Parent component's this.state.ranks, adding to it a separate object per Child IF that Child IS clicked. Obviously above example is kind of stupid but in original code it set's an object of many boolean to create something like a chart.

Anyways, that's not the really the question I want to ask here. What is happening is when the state changes on the Parent, the ChildList gets rerendered. Meaning the whole list gets rerendered. Which can take up to 2~3 seconds depending on how long the list is. This is obviously not good.

I tried to put ChildList in componentWillMount, tried putting in shouldComponentUpdate, and also tried putting ChildList elements in a state but all three meant even with state change, no visual change, ie no rerender occurs.

I can't really move the state in Parent component elsewhere because of other sibling components to Child component that relies on it.

I don't know what to do. Please help.

**EDIT:**

Basically, I want to change a single Child component but ChildList component should not re-render the whole array of Childs.

Comment: I have met similar problem,I solve the problem with react-virtual-list.Only render the visible part of the list

Comment: @gumingfeng thanks. I'll check it out. Was this the only way around for this type of problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Infinite Scrolling of <table /> element in react.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31100313/infinite-scrolling-of-table-element-in-react-js)